# Mono / GTK# mnemonics underline doesn't show in OSX

Tags: mono, monodevelop, osx-mavericks, gtk#, mnemonics

OSX Mavericks 10.9.4, Mono 2.10.12, MonoDevelop 3.1.1

No matter what I do, I can't get the mnemonic underline on my (text) button to show (even when I keep Alt/Command pressed). Here's what I tried:

- Using MonoDevelop's *Stetic* GUI designer with an underscore in the label (e.g. *_test*) and enabling *UseUnderline*
- Creating the button manually with `Button.NewWithMnemonic`
- Creating the button's label manually and setting its `TextWithMnemonic`
- Setting `gtk-enable-mnemonics = 1` and `gtk-auto-mnemonics = 0` *in/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc* (there wasn't any `gtkrc`/`.gtkrc`/`.gtkrc=2.0` file in my home folder)
- Switching my entire GTK theme ([link](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/A-better-GTK-theme-for-Mac-OS-X-td3773892.html))

In all my attempts the button shows and works fine, and the underscore is "swallowed" as expected (i.e. it shows *test* and not *_test*) but the underline doesn't show and the accelerator doesn't work. If I add the accelerator explicitly with `AddAccelerator` it works, but still no underline.

Comment: Mono 2.x and MonoDevelop 3.x are seriously outdated, have you tried using the latest versions (i.e. Mono 3.8 and MonoDevelop 5.4) ?

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger no, I am constrained to use 2.X

Comment: Why are you constrained to 2.x?

Comment: @jstedfast an existing program requires it. I saw the parallel environments page (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments), but it looks like more work than writing the entire small program I need.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there isn't already another widget with the same mnemonic in your window.

Comment: There isn't - I've created a new project with a single button.